# R - Converting one table to multiple table

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file called `data.csv` that contains 3 tables all merged in just one. I would like to separate them in 3 different data.frame when I import it  to R.
So far this is what I have got after running this code:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")
View(df)
Student 
Name    Score
Maria   18
Bob     25
Paul    27
Region  
Country Score
Italy   65
India   99
United  88
Sub region  
City    Score
Paris   77
New     55
Rio     78
```

How can I split them in such a way that I get this result:

First:

```
View(StudentDataFrame)
Name    Score
Maria   18
Bob     25
Paul    27
```

Second:

```
View(regionDataFrame)
Country Score
Italy   65
India   99
United  88
```

Third:

```
View(SubRegionDataFrame)  
City    Score
Paris   77
New     55
Rio     78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to read the dataset with `readLines`, create a grouping variable ('grp') based on the location of 'Student', 'Region', 'Sub region' in the 'lines', `split` it and read it with `read.table`

```
i1 <- trimws(lines) %in% c("Student", "Region", "Sub region")
grp <- cumsum(i1)
lst <- lapply(split(lines[!i1], grp[!i1]), function(x)
             read.table(text=x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE))
lst
#$`1`
#   Name Score
#1 Maria    18
#2   Bob    25
#3  Paul    27

#$`2`
#  Country Score
#1   Italy    65
#2   India    99
#3  United    88

#$`3`
#   City Score
#1 Paris    77
#2   New    55
#3   Rio    78
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("data.csv")
```